# Can I build 32-bit and 64-bit MSI in one Visual Studio build?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix

I'd like to combine 32-bit and 64-bit MSI installers (build by WiX) into one bundle as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15985524/422611). Can I build both the 32-bit and 64-bit installers in one build in Visual Studio or do I need to create an external msbuild script or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no option to build both 32-bit and 64-bit MSI in one Visual Studio build, beaucse it is a build platform configuration and Visual Studio can take only one build platform configuration at a time in one build not two platform configurations in one build.

So, you may need to write a external msbuild script with a command as below:

```
<Target Name="Compile">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MySolution)" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=x86"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MySolution)" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=Release64;Platform=x64"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a solution that includes both the 32 and 64 bit projects and than set the solution configuration to build both of them.