# How do I unify two msi installation packages (64bit and 32bit) created by Windows Installer into one?

Tags: installation

I created 32-bit and 64-bit installation files respectively with Windows Installer. How can I create a unified installation file that can check the bits during installation, and merge these two into one to install automatically according to the bits?

Answer (score 0):

***Heath Stewart***: [**Different Packages are Required for Different Processor Architectures**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/). Here is an extract: *"A common question is how to create a Windows Installer package that installs 32-bit binaries on 32-bit platforms, and both 32- and 64-bit binaries on 64-bit platforms. If you’re actually trying to install 64-bit binaries to appropriate directories and write to the 64-bit view of the registry, the short answer is that you can’t build a single package."*

You should be able to use a setup.exe creation tool such as [WiX's Burn](https://wixtoolset.org/) or [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) or [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com) (all can create **`setup.exe`** launchers). I am unsure of the built-in mechanisms they provide for this at the moment - I haven't looked at it for a while.

In any case you need a 32-bit **`setup.exe`**  so that it can launch on both 32 and 64 bit systems and inside it you can keep your 64-bit setup along with the 32-bit one.

---

***Rob Mensching's*** on the topic: **[How to deploy 64-bit and a 32-bit Windows Installer package as a single setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147498/how-to-deploy-64-bit-and-a-32-bit-windows-installer-package-as-a-single-setup/15985524#15985524)**.

Here is one of his blogs on Burn: https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/lets-talk-about-burn/ and [here is the normal starting point in the WiX documentation for Burn](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/).

Here is my attempt to show [a basic, functional Burn package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071758/129130) (many links - too many - towards the bottom).

---

***Links:***

- [Single MSI to install correct 32 or 64 bit c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724956/single-msi-to-install-correct-32-or-64-bit-c-sharp-application)
- https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/net-and-net/bootstrapping/